# Does "apt-get install zend-framework" install zend 1 or zend 2 on Ubuntu 14 LTS?

Tags: zend-framework

I'm trying to get Zend Framework 1.12. I've looked online, but no one really says which version they're telling you to install.

Comment: Have you looked at https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version ?

Comment: Thanks, @NamelessOne

Comment: `sudo apt-cache policy zend-framework`. Given that only 1.11 is available on 16.04, I'm guessing the answer is 'no'.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently installed ubuntu 15.10 and then install zend framework using this command `sudo apt-get install zend-framework`, it installed  `Zend Framework Version: 1.11.11`